# Jquery validator moves input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got three fields inline and one of them is a inpt field, this is how it look like when they are validated

https://ibb.co/X8c1jDZ

the problem is when I enter some values into the input fiedl then it moves all the other fields as you can see from the image

https://ibb.co/Fn666cw

I believe something is wrong with the way I unhighlight the field once has been filled but not sure, maybe someone can help me. Please let me know if you need more details. many thanks

This is my html code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group fieldGroup">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Tipologia proprietario</label>
        <select class="form-control bs-select" id="kmg_admin_new_building_owner_type-1" name="kmg_admin_new_building_owner_type[]" data-live-search="true" title="Seleziona tipologia proprietario">
          <option value="1">Proprietario</option>
          <option value="2">Co-Proprietario</option>
          <option value="3">Nudo proprietario</option>
          <option value="4">Usufruttuario</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Proprietario</label>
        <select class="form-control bs-select" id="kmg_admin_new_building_owner-1" name="kmg_admin_new_building_owner[]" data-live-search="true" title="Seleziona tipologia proprietario">
          <option value="1">Proprietario</option>
          <option value="2">Co-Proprietario</option>
          <option value="3">Nudo proprietario</option>
          <option value="4">Usufruttuario</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Se
        <span class="required"> * </span>
        </label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control prova" id="kmg_admin_new_building_owner_quota-1" name="kmg_admin_new_building_owner_quota[]" placeholder="Quota titolare">
          <span class="input-group-btn input-group-btn input-space">
          <button class="btn btn-default addMore" type="button">Aggiungi proprietario</button>
          </span>
          <span class="input-group-btn input-group-btn input-space">
          <button class="btn btn-default remove" type="button">Rimuovi proprietario</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript code

```
    form.validate({

        // doNotHideMessage: true, //this option enables to show the error/success messages on tab switch.
        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input

        rules: {
            kmg_admin_new_building_increment: {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                remote: {     
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {
                    ajax_action: 'kmg_new_building_check_increment',
                    kmg_new_building_increment: function() {
                        return $( "#kmg_admin_new_building_increment" ).val();
                    }

                  } 
                }
            },
            kmg_admin_new_building_type: { required: true },
            kmg_admin_new_building_palazzina: { required: true },
            kmg_admin_new_building_interno: { required: true },
            "kmg_admin_new_building_owner_type[]": {required: true},
            "kmg_admin_new_building_owner[]": { required: true },
            "kmg_admin_new_building_owner_quota[]": {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 100
            },
            kmg_admin_new_building_metri: { 
                required: false,
                digits: true 
            }

        },

        messages: {
            kmg_admin_new_building_increment: {
                required: "Specifica un ordine di stampa univoco",
                digits: "L'ordine di stampa può solo essere un numero",
                remote: "Ordine di stampa è già registrato!",
            },
            kmg_admin_new_building_type: "Specifica la tipologia dell'unità immobiliare",
            kmg_admin_new_building_palazzina: "Specifica la palazzina dell'unità immobiliare",
            kmg_admin_new_building_interno: "Inserisci il valore d'interno",
            "kmg_admin_new_building_owner_type[]": "Seleziona tipologia di proprietario",
            "kmg_admin_new_building_owner[]": "Seleziona proprietario",
            "kmg_admin_new_building_owner_quota[]": {
                required: "Specifica la quota",
                number: "solo numeri",
                min: "minimo 0",
                max: "massimo 100"
            },
            kmg_admin_new_building_metri: {digits: "Inserisci valore numerico"}
        },

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) { // render error placement for each input type

            if (element.parent(".input-group").length > 0) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent(".input-group"));

            } else {
                error.appendTo(element.closest('.form-group'));
            }

        },

        invalidHandler: function(event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
            success.hide();
            error.show();
            App.scrollTo(error, -200);
        },

        highlight: function(element) { // hightlight error inputs

            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },

        unhighlight: function(element) { // revert the change done by hightlight

            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group

        },

        success: function(label) {
            label.addClass('valid').closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success'); // set success class to the control group

        },
```

This is how i clone the fields

```
    //add more fields group
    var fieldGroup = $(".fieldGroup").clone();

    // Hide remove button
    $(".remove").parent('span').hide();
    $(".addMore").click(function(e) {
        var fgc = $('body').find('.fieldGroup').length;

        var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group fieldGroup">' + fieldGroup.html() + '</div>';

        fieldHTML = fieldHTML.replace('kmg_admin_new_building_owner_type-1', 'kmg_admin_new_building_owner_type-' + (fgc + 1));
        fieldHTML = fieldHTML.replace('kmg_admin_new_building_owner-1', 'kmg_admin_new_building_owner-' + (fgc + 1));
        fieldHTML = fieldHTML.replace('kmg_admin_new_building_owner_quota-1', 'fkmg_admin_new_building_owner_quota-' + (fgc + 1));

        $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);

        var el = $('.fieldGroup').next();
        // Hide add new button
        el.find('.addMore').parent('span').hide();
        // Show remove button
        el.find('.remove').parent('span').show();

        // Load selectpicker again after cloning the inputs
        $('.bs-select').selectpicker({

            iconBase: 'fa',
            tickIcon: 'fa-check',
            dropupAuto: false
        });
    });

 //remove fields group
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {

        $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a serious problem, I think, you just have to think of the changes of the layout, and prepare for them in your CSS.

Here's an example of what's happening:

(You can find a short explanation at the bottom of the answer.)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(".modify").on('click', function(e) {
    // $.fn.toggle() switches between display: none and
    // display: block
    $('#il3').find('label').toggle()
  })
})
```

```css
.inputandlabel {
  float: left;
}

input[type="text"],
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modify">Just push it to see the problem</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div id="il1" class="inputandlabel">
        <label for="form1">Form1</label>
        <input id="form1" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="il2" class="inputandlabel">
        <label for="form2">Form2</label>
        <input id="form2" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="il3" class="inputandlabel">
        <label for="form3">Form3</label>
        <input id="form3" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="il4" class="inputandlabel">
        <label for="form4">Form4</label>
        <input id="form4" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="il5" class="inputandlabel">
        <label for="form5">Form5</label>
        <input id="form5" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="il6" class="inputandlabel">
        <label for="form6">Form6</label>
        <input id="form6" type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's a solution:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(".modify").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if ($('#il3').find('label').css('visibility') !== 'hidden') {
      $('#il3').find('label').css('visibility', 'hidden')
    } else {
      $('#il3').find('label').css('visibility', 'visible')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.inputandlabel {
  float: left;
}

input[type="text"],
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modify">Just push it to see "nothing"</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div id="il1" class="inputandlabel">
        <label for="form1">Form1</label>
        <input id="form1" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="il2" class="inputandlabel">
        <label for="form2">Form2</label>
        <input id="form2" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="il3" class="inputandlabel">
        <label for="form3">Form3</label>
        <input id="form3" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="il4" class="inputandlabel">
        <label for="form4">Form4</label>
        <input id="form4" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="il5" class="inputandlabel">
        <label for="form5">Form5</label>
        <input id="form5" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="il6" class="inputandlabel">
        <label for="form6">Form6</label>
        <input id="form6" type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see from the two snippets, that by setting `display: none;` on the `label`  scrambles the layout. **`display: none;` takes the element out of the flow** (not the DOM itself, but from the object flow), while **`visibility: hidden;` just makes the element invisible**. Quite a difference, isn't it?

So, setting the display CSS property to none "removes the height" that kept your layout in order - try setting the elements visibility to hidden with JS.

If that's not working, then give the form-group a fixed height (the height with success / error message), and don't change that value on success / error.